# adequacy of connectives and truth table

Tags: logic

### A set of connectives are adequate if you can express all truth table with those connectives.

I dont understand this sentence - what does it mean by you can "express all truth table"? The notes gives this as an example:

> $ \{\vee, \wedge, \rightarrow \}$ is not adequate because any formula
>   has T in the top row of truth table.

I get that truth table for each connectives give a*b = True when a and b are true. But why does it mean I "cannot express all truth table"?

-- in addition, how would i go on about proving that * where

### a b a*b

### T T  F

### T F  T

### F T  F

### F F  T

is not adequate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(For your first set) You could not express $\lnot P$ this way since line $1$ of that is "false".
For more variables, string together several via "ands" but keep the "not" on the first variable, e.g. for 3 vars $ \lnot P \land Q \land R.$

There are only two known single connectives which are truth functionally complete, namely what are called "NAND" and "NOR". The first says P,Q not both true, the second says P,Q are both false.

[Note: as I recall someone actually *proved* that NAND and NOR are the only two single truth functionally complete ones.]

Comment: Thank you very much - that makes it clear